# How to manage concurrency while updating Oracle View through EF in an MVC project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, view, concurrency, oracle10g

My MVC 4 application is using Entity Framework 5 as its ORM.
And an Oracle 10 database is used as its back-end.
MVC Views are displaying data from Oracle DB Views, and I have no control over database schema. 
The Views are updatable, and there is also a requirement of managing concurrency. There is no timestamp sort of column in the underlying table/ view. 
In such scenario, how can I manage concurrency?

Any advice on this will be much appreciated.

Comment: Are other systems updating Oracle underneath or is your website the only entry into it?

Comment: I am not sure if any other website is updating.. our client can't give us more detail on that. But does it make any difference?

Comment: It was just to get an idea of the possible scenarios of it being changed apart from the website. I'll have a think...

Comment: Not at the moment. In my mind, concurrency is primarily a DB issue so if you can't change the DB to add an additional column, then I'm out of ideas. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for the late answer but I just came across this.
As you have no access to the database, it would not be easy at all to prevent 2 users from requesting edit on the same record (even if you did, I am not sure there is a bullet proof way of doing this in a web application). What you can do is prevent a user from editing an object that was modified between the time it was retrieved and the time of change submission. I am going to assume that in your MVC application you are using view models to represent the domain model objects on the screen. You can include as an additional field in the view model a field for a hash computed based on the state of the object at time of retrieval.  When an edit is posted, you would need to retrieve the record again from the database, compare its current hash with the one submitted by the MVC view. In case of discrepancy, inform the user of change and show the values as they are now in the database informing the user of what happened (e.g. by adding a model state error).

Comment: Glad I could be of help :)